# NEXT Function, or test if following Row Group is hidden

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report-builder2.0

I'm using ReportBuilder 2.0 / SQL Server 2008.

I have a report that uses visibility settings on the row groups which results in some row group headings being hidden, which in turn makes report totals seem incorrect. I can't change the visibility settings (for business reasons); what I'm looking for is a way to test EITHER for hidden items, OR for apparently incorrect totals. Consider the following dataset:

```
ItemCode    SubPhaseCode    SubPhase    BidItem     XTDPrice
1           1               Water       Utility 1   5000
2           1               Water       Utility 2   4000
3           2               Electrical  Utility 3   75,000
4           2               Electrical  Utility 3   75,000
5           2               Electrical  Utility 3   100000
6           2               Electrical  Utility 4   2500
7           2               Electrical  Utility 4   2500
8           2               Electrical  Utility 4   5064
9           2               Electrical  Utility 5   3000
10          2               Electrical  Utility 5   3000
11          2               Electrical  Utility 5   5796
12          3               Gas         Utility 6   60000
13          3               Gas         Utility 6   60000
14          3               Gas         Utility 6   61547
15          4               Other       Utility 7   6000
16          4               Other       Utility 7   7000
```

There are 3 Row Groups on the report, one for SubPhaseCode ("Group1"), and two for BidItem("Group2" and "DetailsGroup"):

[Link to Design View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmmla.jpg)

The Row Visibility property for Group1 (**SubPhaseCode**) is:

```
=IIF(Fields!SubPhaseCode.Value = 3, true, false)
```

This results in the heading for the SubPhase "Gas" being hidden. This means that, when the report is run, I get something like the following:

```
Total                     475407

Water                       9000

-Utility 1                  5000
-Utility 2                  4000

Electrical                271860

-Utility 3                250000
-Utility 4                 10064
-Utility 5                 11796
-Utility 6                181547

Other                      13000

-Utility 7                 13000
```

The fact that SubPhase 3 ("Gas") is hidden results in 2 apparent errors:

1) The sum for "Electrical" (271860) appears incorrect for the 4 items below it (because there should be another row heading above "Utility 6")

2) The total of 475407 appears incorrect for the 3 groups below it (9000 + 271860 + 13000).

**What I am looking for**  is a way to change the formatting of the headings (especially the Group Headings) if the numbers below them apparently don't add up. I understand how to implement conditional formatting and have done this for the Total. I am unclear how this could be implemented for the Row Group.

I would basically need some kind of a test, for each Row Heading, to see if the **following** heading would be hidden, according to the rules. This sounds to me like a "NEXT" function, which I know doesn't exist.

Other searches have indicated that I might need to add the desired data to the dataset or modify the underlying SP. Just wondering if there are any simpler solutions.

Thanks much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid to sum the values in the SubPhase group SUM().

Try:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!SubPhaseCode.Value=3,0,Fields!XTDPrice.Value))
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; this doesn't change anything though. For the SubPhase groups that are showing (e.g., "Electrical"), the sum remains the same (because SubPhaseCode never equals 3). The hidden heading (for "Gas" / Utility 6) still remains hidden.

Comment: @mgtech, could you edit your question to include a screenshot of your table in the Design window?

Comment: Question edited with link to Screenshot (also to correct number of groups on report) Thanks!